# Add shortcut to Drupal Module

Tags: module, drupal-7

I need to add the "Module Name" to the shortcut tab in admin. I tried `shortcut_install()` in module.install but it doesn't work. Anyone who has a better idea on how to achieve it without adding it manually?

Answer (score 0):

"I need to add the "Module Name" to the shortcut tab in admin."
you mean by (in admin) admin menu ?
if yes you have you to drupal default toolbar module for admin menu.
then you will see at right corner an arrow for shortcut just click this and then you will see a link "Edit shortcuts" just click this and add new shortcut as you want.
and you are done. 
after that you will see a new shortcut in admin menu shortcut bar.
thanks

Comment: need to do all this stuff with a Plugin.